# App Settings multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have to check in the code if the user has acess to the tool,i use this line to do this:

```
 var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[APPSETTINGS.SUPPORTUSERS].ToUpper();
 if ((loggedUser.Login.ToUpper() != appSetting))
```

The problem is in in the web.config file i have this:

```
<add key="SupportUsers" value="sis8ca"/>
```

I'm trying to put multiple values in this string,like    "sis8ca , dts8ca , lgu8ca",if the person has acess,she can use it,but i cant pass multiple values like this,is there other way?

Comment: Use `split()` function to split on `,` comma and then check if one of the values are equal in order to gain access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this in your settings file:

```
<add key="SupportUsers" value="sis8ca,dts8ca,lgu8ca"/>
```

Then in your code behind do the following:

```
var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[APPSETTINGS.SUPPORTUSERS].ToUpper();

string[] supportUsers = appSetting.Split(',');
if (supportUsers.Contains(loggedUser.Login.ToUpper()))
{
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to set a delimiter, and use `string.Split` on that:

```
<add key="SupportUsers" value="sis8ca;dts8ca;lgu8ca"/>

var supportedUsers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportUsers"]
                                         .Split(';')
                                         .ToList();

if (values.Contains(loggedUser.Login))
{
   // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass multiple values by `comma(,)` separator and then when you call that key value use `split`

for eg.

```
string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[APPSETTINGS.SUPPORTUSERS].ToUpper();
string[] words = val.Split(',');
```

you will get list of that `words`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<add key="SupportUsers" value="sis8ca;dts8ca;lgu8ca"/>
```

And the logic to check it:

```
var users = appSetting.Split(new[]{';'});
var hasAccess = users.Contains(loggedUser);

if (hasAccess){ 
   ...
}
```